# Eloquent Relationships hasMany use loop

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I have a database with multiple address records of a user. When I do "pluck()" and "join()" in the foreach path, I get results. But when I type **$user->getAddress->address** in structures like hasOne, I get the result I want. In short, can I return the loop in hasMany more practically?

Following my code:

`user` Table

```
id |    name       | lastname |
--- --------------  ----------   

1  | Rahuel        | lastnameRahuel
2  | Dalton Miller | lastnameDalton
```

`adress` Table

```
user_id | address         
-------- ---------
1       | 740 Brown Greens Suite  
1       | 9906 Cleora Wall Apt.      
2       | 53977 Kip Center Apt
```

`UserModel`

```
 public function getAddress()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Address::class);
    }
```

`Controller`

```
$users = User::with('getAddress')->get();

        foreach ($users as $user){
            echo $user->name;
            echo $user->lastname;
            echo $user->getAdress->pluck('address')->join(',');
        }
```

Comment: not sure what would be more practically for you

Comment: `echo $user->getAdress->pluck('address')->join(',');` I am looking for another usage method other than this usage.

Comment: you could create an accessor on `User` that returns that value ... side note, would be nice for that relationship to be named plural since it returns many `addresses`

Comment: Thank you :))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Collection` 's [`implode`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-implode) method to make it look a bit less verbose.

```php
echo $user->getAdress->implode('address', ',');
```

Comment: Thank you so much